# When playing Age of Empires 3 on Windows 7, how do I get the screen to appear in the center?

Tags: windows-7, age-of-empires-iii

I just installed AOE 3 on my Windows 7 x64 Ultimate box, which has an i5 processor and a radeon 3850.  I have installed the latest AOE 3 patch (1.14).  My video driver, claims windows, is up to date.  The game seems to run fine, but the display is off-center far to the left.  I can only barely see the right edge of the menu buttons.  I can't even read what the buttons say.  But I can click the buttons and the game responds.

In short, how do I get the screen to appear in the center?

Comment: What kind of monitor do you have? LCD or CRT?

Comment: Try visiting you respective video card website and updating. You might also have some luck running the game in compatibility mode (I think I had the same issue with AOE2).

Comment: @DJ Pirtu: it is a DELL LCD

Comment: @Mystagogue Damn. If it had been CRT, it might have been the display settings for that paticular screen resolution. Never the less, trying out different resolutions for the game might be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Check the resolution settings of the game in the options and see if it is set to the same resolution as your monitor.  If not, then set it and hopefully that will work.

Also, if AOE has a windowed mode, you may be able to enable that and then position the window in the center (again, in the options.)

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like it's trying to run at a resolution that your monitor can't display natively.